# array manipulation idea

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have two arrays.

```
$Array1 = array("Maza", "Nissan","Tacoma","Cobalt","Explorer");
```

and second array is

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'In Stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'In stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars/Toyota/Tacoma'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Out of Stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars/Toyota/Celica'
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'In Stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars/Ford/Fusion'
    ),
    (int) 4 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Out of Stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars/Ford/Explorer'
    ),
    (int) 5 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'In Stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars/Chevy/Cobalt'
    ),
    (int) 6 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'In Stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars/Nissan'
    )

)
```

Now I want to see what cars in stock or not based on the first and second array. So for Cobalt, it will return me In Stock, where as for Explorer, it will return me out of stock. And for Mazda it can retun "Do not carry" Where I am confused is wheher or not to explode the array[1] by slash"/" and then lookinto it. Is there another easier/faster way to do it. thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Also, how should Explorer return "out of stock" when there are two instances of it indicating both "out of stock" and "in stock"?

Comment: Do you *have* to have the second array the way you have it? Is it an option to have a different data model for car availability, than what you show there? How often do you look up car availability and how often to you "reload" the information from second array?

Comment: fixed explorer issue and edited it

Comment: I have to load it pretty often

Comment: can a car be 'out of stock' and "in stock" like Ford in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$cars = array("Maza", "Nissan","Tacoma","Cobalt","Explorer");
$stocks=array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'In Stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'In stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars/Toyota/Tacoma'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Out of Stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars/Toyota/Celica'
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'In Stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars/Ford/Fusion'
    ),
    (int) 4 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Out of Stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars/Ford/Explorer'
    ),
    (int) 5 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'In Stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars/Chevy/Cobalt'
    ),
    (int) 6 => array(
        (int) 0 => 'In Stock',
        (int) 1 => 'Cars/Nissan'
    )

);
$output=array();
foreach ($cars as $car) {
   foreach ($stocks as $stock) {
    if(in_array($car, explode('/', $stock[1]))){
        $output[$car]=$stock[0]; 
        break;
        }else{$output[$car]='Do not care';}
} 
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```

This will print:

```
Array
(
    [Maza] => Do not care
    [Nissan] => In Stock
    [Tacoma] => In stock
    [Cobalt] => In Stock
    [Explorer] => Out of Stock
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
$Array1 = array("Maza", "Nissan","Tacoma","Cobalt","Explorer");
$secondarray = array(
    array('In Stock', 'Cars'),
    array('In stock', 'Cars/Toyota/Tacoma'),
    array('Out of Stock', 'Cars/Toyota/Celica'),
    array('In Stock', 'Cars/Ford/Explorer'),
    array('Out of Stock', 'Cars/Ford/Explorer'),
    array('In Stock', 'Cars/Chevy/Cobalt'),
    array('In Stock', 'Cars/Nissan'));
function findcar($car, $secondarray) {
    for($c = 0; $c <= count($secondarray); $c++) {
        if(strpos(strtolower($secondarray[$c][1]), strtolower($car)) > 0) {
                return $secondarray[$c][0];
        }
    }
}

echo findcar($Array1[1], $secondarray);
```

this would print out `In Stock`, if a car wasn't found it just returns nothing.

Comment: No, $car is the car you want to look for, like $Array1[1] for "Nissan"

Comment: $secondarray has to be the second array, which you could actually create a bit easier, ill update the code above.

Comment: I just tested it just takes some words

Comment: Okay, I again changed the code again a few times, now it really works. Be sure you have the latest code (above)